# Linq expression for executing a "Between"

Tags: c#, linq, between

In SQL you have the ability to write a query that executes a between on a column that is of type 'nvachar' and simply returns to you all the rows that are between the min and max values specified.

For Example,

```
Table (Id:Int, Name:nvarchar):

Contents:
1, Annie
2, Bill
3, Frank
4, Phil
5, Ted

Select * where Name Between 'Frank' and 'Ted'

Should return Frank, Phil, and Ted.
```

Is there a way to do this with linq or am I going to have to create a custom query and execute it?  The only examples I have seen involve dates or integers which make it very easy (can use the comparison operators like <, > etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd use `CompareTo` instead:

```
var query = from name in names
            where name.CompareTo("Frank") >= 0 &&
                  name.CompareTo("Ted") <= 0
            select name;
```

Use `>` and `<` to be exclusive (i.e. to exclude Frank and Ted).

Basically it's the same as using `<` and `>`, but with methods :)

Comment: @Reed: I wasn't sure about that, not having read the question carefully enough. Will edit to make it clear.

Comment: That was entirely too simple.  Thanks Jon, This is exactly what I needed. :)

Comment: @The Sheek Geek: Cool - glad to hear it :)