# Getting items from a database between a specific number of values

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Hi I recently learned entity framework and linq and I was asked to convert this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetBooks]
@numberOfBooksOnPage int,
@pageNumber int
    AS
    BEGIN

    WITH AllBooks AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS RowId,
        Id , Name , Author , Description , PublicationDate , CategoryId
        FROM Books
    )

    SELECT Id , Name , Author , Description , PublicationDate , CategoryId
    FROM AllBooks
    WHERE RowId BETWEEN ((@pageNumber - 1) * @numberOfBooksOnPage) + 1 AND @pageNumber * @numberOfBooksOnPage
    ORDER BY RowID
    END
```

So far I only managed to get the total number of books to be displayed per page , but I still need to find a way to get the books via a pageNumber.

This is what I have so far:

```
var books = bookContext.Books.Take(numberOfBooksOnPage);
```

So how can I represent what is written in the stored procedure in my linq query?

Comment: Search this site:  linq between, you'll get plenty of examples. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235859/linq-expression-for-executing-a-between

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do an easy paging, here's a quick solution:

```
var books = bookContext.Books.OrderBy(x => x.Id).Skip(pageNo*booksPerPage).Take(booksPerPage);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Skip() method in conjunction with take

```
var books = bookContext.Books.OrderBy(b => b.Id).Skip(pageNumber * numberOfBooksOnPage).Take(numberOfBooksOnPage)
```

Comment: Yes, because all sequences have some order but you door need to specify an order explicitly to ensure you get the data in the order you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

You want [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb358985.aspx) -

```
var books = bookContext.Books.OrderBy(b => b.someField).Skip(pageNumber * numberOfBooksOnPage).Take(numberOfBooksOnPage);
```

Answer (score 1):

Paging in LINQ typically involves use of the `Skip` and `Take` extensions, so:

```
var numOfBooksPerPage = 20;
var currPage = 3;

var books = bookContext.Books.Skip(currPage * numOfBooksPerPage).Take(numOfBooksPerPage);
```

Answer (score 1):

As said if you want to page your result it's better to use **Take** in conjunction with **Skip** as in the previous answers.
Linq to sql doesn't expose a **Between** method, this can be easily replaced with a **Where** clause. Alternatively you can write your own extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Between<TSource, TResult>
(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector,
    TResult lowest, TResult highest
)
    where TResult : IComparable<TResult>
{
    return source.OrderBy(selector).
        SkipWhile(s => selector.Invoke(s).CompareTo(lowest) < 0).
        TakeWhile(s => selector.Invoke(s).CompareTo(highest) <= 0 );
}
```

And give it a try:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Pages { get; set; }
}    

[Test]
public void TestBooks()
{
    var listOfNumbers = new List<Book>() {new Book(){Pages = 10}, new Book(){Pages = 44}};
    var result = listOfNumbers.Between(x => x.Pages, 0, 29);
}
```